# Create a WAR file by using Maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Is it possible to create a war file by using the **maven assembly plugin** or is this plugin only for creating a jar files?

What is necessary to configure in the Maven assembly plugin to to create a war file?

I don´t want to use the maven war plugin, since I need some more possibilities for my war file (for example two different output directories for my specific war file, I mean the target path and an another path in my maven project). And this is no problem by using the maven assembly plugin, if I create a jar file with this plugin.

Comment: use two separate execution block instead of maven-assembly...

Answer (score 4):

In the maven-assembly-plugin, you define the name of the .war file (I called it ROOT because it´s the main application) and the phase when the plugin should be executed. The appendAssemblyId property defines if "-war" should be appended to the file name (e.g. "ROOT-war.war").

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>war-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The structure of the resulting .war file needs to be configured in a separate xml file which is called "web-assembly.xml" (you can specify any name). In this descriptor file, the files and directories and the corresponding output directory in the .war file needs to be specified.

```
<assembly>
    <id>war</id>
    <formats>
        <format>war</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                 <exclude>*:war</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>/**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        ...
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The maven-assembly-plugin gives you a great flexibility of how to structure your output artifact. But you also need to copy dependencies, class files and resources separately which can be quite complex. The maven-war-plugin does all of this for you.